# methods in contextBridge not working in child window

Tags: vue.js, electron

I use quasar framework for development.
In child windows, I cannot call the code of my myWindowAPI, do you know why?

In electron-preload.ts I have this

```
function createWindow() {
  let x, y;
  const currentWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  if (currentWindow) {
    const [currentWindowX, currentWindowY] = currentWindow.getPosition();
    x = currentWindowX + 24;
    y = currentWindowY + 24;
  }
  let newWindow: Electron.CrossProcessExports.BrowserWindow | undefined;
  newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    x,
    y,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      //nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
    }
  });
  //newWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);
  newWindow.loadURL(process.env.APP_URL);
  newWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  newWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    if (!newWindow) {
      throw new Error('"newWindow" is not defined');
    }
    if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
      newWindow.minimize();
    } else {
      newWindow.show();
      newWindow.focus();
    }
  });
  newWindow.on('closed', () => {
    //windows.delete(newWindow);
    newWindow = undefined;
  });
  /*newWindow.on('focus', () => {
    const menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(newWindow);
    menuBuilder.buildMenu();
  });*/
  //windows.add(newWindow);
  return newWindow;
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myWindowAPI', {

  
  ajouterFenetre () {
    createWindow()
  },

  envoi (data: unknown) {
    //BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.webContents.send('ping', data)
    console.log('envoi', data)
    ipcRenderer.send('ping', data)
  },

  on: () => {
        // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
        ipcRenderer.on('ping2', (event, data) => {
            console.log('recoi 1', data)
        })
  },

  recoi: (func:(data: unknown) => void) => {
    //if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
    // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
    return ipcRenderer.on('ping2', (event, data) => {
        console.log('recoi 1', data)
    })
    //ipcRenderer.on('ping', (event, data) => func(data))
    //}
  },

  /*recoi: () => new Promise((res) => {
    ipcRenderer.on('ping', (ev, data) => {
        console.log('recoi 1', data)
      res(data);
    });
  }),*/

  minimize () {
    console.log('minimize2')
    //BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.minimize()
  },

  toggleMaximize () {
    const win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()

    if (win?.isMaximized()) {
      win.unmaximize()
    } else {
      win?.maximize()
    }
  },

  close () {
    BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.close()
  }
})
```

In the main window, the methods myWindowAPI working but not in another window created by method createWindow.
I call in my vue component the method

```
window.myWindowAPI?.ajouterFenetre()
```

Why is working only in main window ?

Answer (score 0):

A preload script has to be attached to a window to be accessible:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
});
```

Additionaly, if you want to use the same preload for both window, it means you need to move your window creation code on the main process, outside of the preload file, because you can't link a file if you're within it. It simply means adding an extra IPC handler, as per [the official example in the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-1-renderer-to-main-one-way):

**renderer**

```js
window.myWindowAPI?.createWindow();
```

**electron-preload.ts**

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myWindowAPI', {
  createWindow: () => ipcRenderer.send('create-window'),
  ...
}
```

**electron-main.ts**

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  ...
};

ipcMain.on('create-window', createWindow);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I have this error: `Unable to load preload script: C:\DEV\electron\electron\.quasar\electron\preload.js`
The preload file is not found.
I also tried with this code same error : `preload: path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD),`

Comment: @FrançoisSchuster You have to set the correct path based on your folder structure. Obviously, you can't link the preload file if you create the window inside this file. It would means the path is `path.join(__dirname, ".")`. Try to move the window creation code on main instead.

Comment: If I move the window creation code into the main, how then can I call it in preload in contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myWindowAPI'?

Comment: @FrançoisSchuster You can use IPC listeners on main too, [here is the example from the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-1-renderer-to-main-one-way), I will edit my question to provide an example.

Comment: I have one last problem.
I'm trying to communicate information between windows.
The send (envoi) method allows you to send data to other windows.
The receive method (recoi) allows you to receive data sent through a window.
Uploading (envoi) works well now in all windows.
Reception only works (recoi) in the main window.
Why? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: To send the data to the child windows, I stored my child windows in an array, is this the right solution?
`ipcMain.on('ping', (e, data) => {
    console.log('ipcMain', data)
    mainWindow?.webContents.send('ping2', data)
    childWindow.forEach(window => {
      window.webContents.send('ping2', data)
    });
  })`

To close the window I use this code but it doesn't work for child windows.
`BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.close()`

How can we close the child windows?

Comment: Sorry it's work with add this `enable(newWindow.webContents)`

Comment: @FrançoisSchuster I think your initial question is solved. If you have another question, please ask a new question with your current code. The comments section is not the place for advanced help.